# Django model not casting date field to datetime.date?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-datetime

Let's write a simple Django model with a **DateField**:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  my_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a strange issue when then creating objects:

```
m1 = MyModel.objects.create(my_date=date.today())
print(type(m1.my_date)) # => <class 'datetime.date'>

m2 = MyModel.objects.create(my_date="2020-01-14")
print(type(m2.my_date)) # => <class 'str'>
```

So... Contrary to what I read in the [doc of the Django DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield) ("*A date, represented in Python by a datetime.date instance*"), it seems like Django does not cast the value to a `datetime.date` instance if the date is provided as a str when creating the object?

Comment: The field does not convert this to at the attribute level. It will convert that and store it in the aratbase. Later when you *fetch* the record from the database, it will be a `date`/`datetime` object.

Comment: Wah, you're very quick… and right. Just tested. That feels weird to me, btw. Thanks a lot Willem!

Answer (score 4):

A field does not *proactively* convert the attribute to a certain type. When you *store* it in the database, it will convert it to a `date`/`datetime` field, and later when you retrieve it from the database, it will be a `date`/`datetime` field.

Indeed, take the following example:

```
m2 = MyModel.objects.create(my_date="2020-01-14")
m3 = MyModel.objects.get(m2.pk)
print(type(m3.my_date)) # => <class 'datetime.date'>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Willem, just what I needed. I don't really like this behavior, but anyway, I'll live with it ;)